# simplify this query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT COUNT( sendbook.id ) AS total, SUM( sendbook.num ) AS num, (

SELECT COUNT( sendbook.id )
FROM sendbook
INNER JOIN clients ON clients.id = sendbook.clientid
WHERE sendbook.issueid = '29'
AND clients.area >1000
AND clients.area <2000
) AS area1000, (

SELECT COUNT( sendbook.id )
FROM sendbook
INNER JOIN clients ON clients.id = sendbook.clientid
WHERE sendbook.issueid = '29'
AND clients.area >2000
AND clients.area <3000
) AS area2000, (

SELECT COUNT( sendbook.id )
FROM sendbook
INNER JOIN clients ON clients.id = sendbook.clientid
WHERE sendbook.issueid = '29'
AND clients.area >3000
AND clients.area <4001
) AS area2000
FROM `sendbook`
WHERE sendbook.issueid = '29' 

total  num  area1000  area2000  area2000
 8      438      3         3        2
```

Do you know a  way to simplify this query?
Thinks

Comment: shouldn't your second 'area2000' be named 'area3000'? what happens with areas 2000 and 3000 - this ones aren't considered in your query, is this correct? some more general information would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use case statement  something like this :

```
SELECT  COUNT( sendbook.id ),
(CASE 
WHEN clients.area between '1000' and '2000'  THEN 1 
WHEN clients.area between '2000' and '3000'  THEN 2 
WHEN clients.area between '3000' and '4000'  THEN 3 
 END) AS myrange  FROM mytable 
GROUP BY myrange
```

Comment: your case is 4 rows,but my case is 1 row

Comment: yes but is very simple query, you only need to run a little loop